# Stemming a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, stemming

I have tweet dataset (taken from NLTK) which is currently in a pandas dataframe, but I need to stem it. I have tried many different ways and get some different errors, such as

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'
and
KeyError: 'text'
```

I dont understand the KeyError as the column is definitely called 'text', however I understand that I need to change the dataframe to a string in order for the stemmer to work (I think).

[Here is an example of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFmeJ.png)

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")

negative_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('negative_tweets.json')

negtweetsdf = DataFrame(negative_tweets,columns=['text'])

print(stemmer.stem(negtweetstr))
```

Comment: Hi Richie, unfortunatley I have changed the code since then. I will try and recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the stemming function to the series as follows

```
negtweetsdf.apply(stemmer.stem)
```

This will create a new series.

Functions that expect a single string value or similar will not simply work on a pandas dataframe or series. They need to be applied to the entire series, which is why `.apply` is used.

Here is a worked example with lists inside a dataframe column.

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['some extremely exciting tweet'],['another']], columns=['tweets'])

# put the strings into lists
df = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(list,axis=1), columns=['tweets'])

# for each row (apply) for each item in the list, apply the stemmer
# return a list containing the stems
df['tweets'].apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
```

Comment: stem() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Hi, I get this error with that code

Comment: Remove `axis=1` sorry

Comment: I still get the same error of "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'"

Comment: That's because you have stored lists in your column. The stem function is expecting strings. I will modify the example for you.

Comment: Is it good practice to store as strings rather than lists? I have 2 other datasets of the same style, if so I will change those too.

Also, when I do negtweets['text'] I get a KeyError, even though the only column in there is named text. Do you know why that is?

Comment: The column is called "tweets" in the example. Use `df.columns` to see the names of the columns. In your case, you have varying sentence lengths so it makes sense to store lists in the column as you don't know how many columns you'd need. In general though, it's not good practice to store lists in dataframes. A good feature of pandas is it's fast inbuilt operations. These are not available when using apply. You may want to look at your data structure if you find the process becoming too slow.

Comment: I think theres an underlying issue then, i did negtweets.columns and get the error " 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' " which I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: A series doesn't have columns, it has a name. Try `negtweets.name`. You can view the attributes of an object with `__dir__(negtweets)` and you can view the type with `type(negtweets)`. These concepts are very helpful in python development.

Comment: So I did negtweets.name and can confirm it is named text. So I dont know why i get a KeyError when carrying out your code.

Comment: If you're working with a series, just do `negtweets.apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])` as there is no column to name.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. I thought I was working with a dataframe all this time. Sorry about that. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped, please accept it with an upvote.

Comment: I dont have enough rep for a visible upvote, but I did!